# Create pandas period range without leap days

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working with a scientific model that doesn't consider leap days - every year has exactly 365 days.

I want to create a pandas period range without leap days. Is this the best way to achieve it?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pandas
periods = pandas.period_range('1900-01-01', '2019-12-31')
is_leap_day = (periods.month == 2) & (periods.day == 29)
periods_without_leap = periods[~is_leap_day]
```

Comment: Seems reasonable can't think of anything wrong with this approach

Comment: The code you posted looks good. I don't think pandas includes any specific functionality to achieve what you are after here either, if that's what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I've written a wrapper function for `period_range` that provides a `without_leap` keyword argument.

```
def period_range(*args, without_leap=False, **kwargs):
    """Wraps period_range, removing leap days"""
    periods = pandas.period_range(*args, **kwargs)
    if without_leap:
        is_leap_day = (periods.month == 2) & (periods.day == 29)
        periods = periods[~is_leap_day]
    return periods
```